# PBS non-uniform process request and qstat output

Tags: cluster-computing, openmpi, pbs, torque

I'm working on a 18 node cluster, running TORQUE/PBS Pro/Open MPI.

Setup - 2 CPUs/node, 12 cores/CPU (so 24 allowable process per node).

If I submit PBS jobs that need an uneven split across the nodes, e.g. a job that requires say 58 process, I can split it via:

```
#PBS -l nodes=2:ppn=24+1:ppn=10
```

which assigns 2 nodes using all 24 cores, and 1 node using 10 cores. So I should now have 58 tasks running.

However, when I execute `qstat -a`, the output says I only have 48 tasks running. It never seems to count the unevenly split node/s.

So, are those extra 10 processes actually running? What's going on? Is the output from `qtsat` just incorrect?

I've scrounged through all the PBS readmes/mans I could find, no luck.

Comment: What does your job script look like?